# SQL - XML Parsing from a non-standard XML format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

We have a third party app which generates an XML file with data which is submitted from a mobile device; this comes back into a SQL Database Table and sits inside an XML type field.

I need to pull out specific answers which I seem to have figured out to a certain extend but I would like to know if I could make this work with the 'nodes' or some form of Outer Apply/Cross Apply Join to then query direct rather than a full line per value.

Examples below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zz_PhoneData_Test](
    [RecID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TasksetID] [bigint] NULL,
    [FormData] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [reports].[zz_PhoneData_Test] ([RecID],[TasksetID], [FormData]) VALUES (35512921264, 593, N'<fd u="=afa01113c0674a3fbdc8354c7aa538ab" b="0" v="1"><field i="1">12345</field><field i="2">E-mail Test</field><field i="3">1</field></fd>')





WITH [cte_test] AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10)
           [pd].[RecId],
           REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(FormData.query('/fd/field[@i=1]') AS NVARCHAR(100)),'<field i="1">',''),'</field>','') AS [Order]
    FROM reports.[zz_PhoneData_Test] [pd]
)

SELECT  [cte].[RecId],
        [cte].[Order],
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', [Order] ) = 1 THEN 'Valid'
             WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', [Order] ) = 1 THEN 'Valid'
             WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', [Order] ) = 1 THEN 'Valid'
             ELSE 'Invalid' END AS [Validation]
FROM [cte_test] [cte]
GO
```

With the above it should be enough to get you an example of where I am up to, ignore the PATINDEX as that can be left out of testing, I want to be able to pull the values for each of the 3 answers in the "XML" without using the 'query' option but via the 'nodes' method, although I'm not to sure on how to do this? Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method like so:

```sql
SELECT t.RecID
     , t.TasksetID
     , n.field.value('@i', 'INT') AS attr
     , n.field.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS text
FROM PhoneData AS t
CROSS APPLY t.FormData.nodes('/fd/field') AS n(field)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for although it comes out in several lines for the one ID, I assume I need to PIVOT to get this one line per RecId?

Comment: If there are exactly three answers you can ditch the cross apply and use `FormData.value('(/fd/field)[1]', 'VARCHAR'), FormData.value('(/fd/field)[2]', 'VARCHAR'), FormData.value('(/fd/field)[3]', 'VARCHAR')`

Comment: I appreciate the responses, the example I gave was more for simplicity, these answers could range from around 15-200 set questions depending which form a user submits. If it was only small range I would write each one like you have mentioned, although I think for the bigger ones it would be a pain but if that's the method that has to be used to gain the most efficient/best result then I'll do that.

Comment: Yes, PIVOT would be more appropriate if the number of column is not fixed.